# f4v player with no controls

Tags: jquery, flash, flv, embedded-flashplayer

Does anybody know of any F4V players but where we can disable or hide the controls, i.e. so the web users can't pause / forward / stop the videos..

This is for an internal website so it's not like we're trying to be awkward to end users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any pre-built players, because I prefer to roll my own. But if you have Flash Professional, you can very easily create your own video player using the FLVPlayback component. When you import an F4V video to stage, a wizard will walk you through configuring the component, and as part of that wizard you can choose to have no chrome on the player.

By default it will hard-code the URL to your video file in the FLVPlayback settings. If you need it to be able to play any F4V file, just add the following code to your document class:

```
myFlvComponent.source = root.loaderInfo.parameters['video'];
```

You can then control at embed-time what video to play by defining a flashvar called `video`, e.g. through the SWF query string:

```
myPlayer.swf?video=http://example.com/path/to/video.f4v
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not treally into flash to be honest, just need a player to play videos.